# Speech Production Process

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

I am studying Speech Recognition from Rabiner's book. In this book the author has asked a question 
**Explain the distinct speech production process for producing voiced, unvoiced and plosive sounds**
 The author says : 
 When vocal cord is tensed + air flow then voiced sound
When vocal cord is relaxed + air flow then unvoiced sound
But nothing is said about plosive sound, yes he does mentions about transient sound.
**So is transient sound same as plosive sound?**

Comment: +1 for an Interesting question but it may be a little too far off-topic for a general programming site.

Comment: So could please mention a site where i can ask such questions ?

Comment: I would if I knew one, sorry. That's why I haven't voted to close and +1'd. Hopefully someone else on here can either give you a an answer or point you at a better site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you are categorizing things may be confusing you. Voiced and unvoiced are two types of sounds in a particular category. Plosive sounds could be either voiced or unvoiced; it is not a third type of sound in the same category.

As for your original question, I would not consider plosive and transient sounds to be equivalent. Plosive sounds are when you temporarily block air from exiting and then release it all at once--think about making a 'b' or 'p' sound. Transient sounds are like clicks, pops, or bangs. A short, impulsive sound. Plosives can be similar, but they can also be more extended in duration.

One more thing about vocal cords. I think that terminology gives the wrong image. You don't have cords or strings in your throat that are tensed or relaxed. You have two folds that can come together or remain open. An unvoiced sound is when the folds are relaxed and apart. A voiced sound is when the folds are beating against each other at a regular interval, many times per second.